# Why do operations between scalars and ndarrays work when the scalar is on the left?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given some class, you can implement the basic binary operations (`__add__`, `__sub__`, etc.) and be able to perform `obj1 + obj2` or `obj1 + 3`, but for obvious reasons `3 + obj1` would fail as it is unlikely the built in python types will handle your class.

I never thought about it much and just figured that was how things were until I realized there are examples of `3 + obj1` being done successfully. For example:

```
import numpy as np

obj1 = np.array([1,2,3])

3 + obj1
Out[19]: array([4, 5, 6])
```

How can I allow my class to be used successfully in operations between python built in types on the left, and my object on the right?

```
class DataStruct:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

def __add__(self,other):
    if isinstance(other,DataStruct):
        x = self._x + other._x
        y = self._y + other._y
    else:
        x = self._x + other
        y = self._y + other
    return DataStruct(x,y)
def __repr__(self):
    return f'{self._x},{self._y}'


obj1 = DataStruct(1,2)


obj2 = DataStruct(2,4)


obj1 + obj2
Out[33]: 3,6

obj1 + 3
Out[34]: 4,5

3 + obj1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-056b6e7e1462>", line 1, in <module>
    3 + obj1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DataStruct'
```

Comment: that is what `__radd__` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The magic function you're looking for is `__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__), which handles addition when your class is on the right-hand side of an addition. There's a whole suite of these `__r<OPERATOR>__` functions to handle these cases in general, which you need to implement in addition to just `__add__` if you want to support your class being in both positions (it's not assumed that the operation is always commutative).

Comment: Also, note that `__radd__` exists so your class can distinguish between `obj1 + 3` and `3 + obj` when its `+` operation is non-commutative.